# Prove that the sequence is a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

The Sequence ${a_n}$ satisfies the following condition ::

$|a_{n+1} - a_n|$ $\leq$ $\alpha$$|a_n-a_{n-1}|$,   $0<\alpha <1 $ for all natural numbers $n\geq2$

I approached the question like this ::

In a field of real numbers, A sequence is convergent iff it's cauchy. So I tried to prove that the sequence is convergent using monotone convergence theorem. Using Induction, I first proved that the sequence is monotonous. And again using induction, trying to prove that it is bounded, but I am stuck here.

Apart form this, I think applying Cauchy's general principle of convergence to prove this would be a more neater technique.
Cauchy's General principle of Convergence states that the necessary and sufficient condition for convergence of a sequence ${S_n}$ is that for each $\epsilon$, there exists an $m$ such that

$|S_{n+p}-S_n| < \epsilon$, $\forall n>m$ and   $p\geq1$

Please let me know how this can be approached by either of the ways. Thanks.

Comment: This sequence $a_n$ need not be monotonic, so you can't have proven it is monotonic.  Perhaps you're talking about a related sequence, but this is not apparent.

Comment: I do not think you can conclude that it is monotonic. It can be oscillating, each new oscillation being a fraction of the previous.

Comment: Proof given in the text of the linked _question_ itself.

Comment: I am curious about the if and only if statement. If a sequence is cauchy, it need not be convergent.

Comment: In a field of real numbers, a sequence is convergent iff it is Cauchy sequence. 
I have edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is telescoping in nature as evident by what is given. See below a sketch. Also, recall that $\alpha^n \to 0$ when $0<\alpha < 1$

Suppose $m > n $, then

$$ |a_m - a_n| = | a_m - a_{m-1} + a_{m-1} - a_{m-2} + a_{m-2} - ... + a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq |a_m - a_{m-1}| + |a_{m-1} - a_{m-2}| + ... + |a_{n+1} -a_n| \leq \alpha^m |a_3-a_2| + \alpha^{m-1} |a_3-a_2| + ... + \alpha^n |a_3 - a_2| = \sum_{k=n}^m \alpha^k |a_3-a_2| $$

Comment: The exponents on $\alpha$ need to be decreased by $3$... Note that $m=3, n=2$ applied to your inequality would give $$|a_3-a_2| \leq \alpha^3|a_3-a_2| + \alpha^2|a_3-a_2|$$ which would be false for $\alpha$ small enough (around $\alpha < 3/4$).